# Javascript Make Div appear for 2 seconds after mouse press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been having problems with creating a colored block which is hidden, and then appears after a mouse press (no where specific, anywhere on the page), then stays there for 2 seconds and then disappears again... until another mouse press happens, and the whole thing happens again. Have been experimenting with '.click(function' and other things but haven't been able to make it work.

At the moment I have a DIV layer like this...

HTML:

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.overlay {
position: absolute; 
z-index: 1000;
right: 240px;
top: 500px;
width: 1000px;
height: 100px;
background: rgba(255, 255, 200, 100);
}
```

I'm quite new to javascript so any advice will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery(document) does the trick as it will consider click for the whole document and not to a specific place on page.

```js
jQuery(document).click(function(event) {
    var $div = $(".overlay");
    if ($div.is(":visible")) { return; }
    $div.show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $div.hide();
    }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Doing this you do need a target div or element to fire an event on click. This will allow you to fire the event on the whole document.

Comment: @Elysium Design try this code. And tell what you want in this if need an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `setTimeout` in jQuery

```js
$( "#target" ).on( "click", function() {
  $("#messageBox").hide().slideDown();
  setTimeout(function(){
      $("#messageBox").hide();        
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
#messageBox {
    display:inline-block;
 float:right;
 border:1px solid #060;
 background:#FFC;
 padding:10px 20px;
 box-shadow:2px 2px 4px #666;
 color:#060;
 font-weight:bold;
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="messageBox">
  Hi there.
</div>
<input type="button" id ="target" value="click"/>
```